# extract all substring occurances starting with certain character with set length

Tags: php

Looking for help to extract all sub-string occurrences beginning with 2017 (the current year) and the next 60 characters (total 64 chars). The sub-string should not contain any spaces.

The string may come from a variety of sources i.e. HTTP header or DNS lookups so the structure of the string will be different. However, what I need to extract will always be the same (length 64 chars and sub-string starting with the current year YYYY).

Example of string:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 02:34:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: xyz

201712140148264celho2kam2t3ajsf3zaiwvwl424nb16es5n8r81ajbgvvo175201712140153182vfdqczsdjvss09ikk7xoannmzyhxwl1q3d8kcsnwmfenacqvz
201712151016343f6fnxgkjpjuzemgp4pbay4s5aagky5bsa5t4wns7ka1admgzp
```

In the above examples, there are 3 occurrences that match the criteria, two are on the same line (64 chars) and one on a separate lines (64 chars).

** please note: 2017 in the header for the date should not be extracted as the next 60 characters contain spaces.

I want to be able to take all 3 and put into an array

```
Array
(
    [1] => 201712140148264celho2kam2t3ajsf3zaiwvwl424nb16es5n8r81ajbgvvo175
    [2] => 201712140153182vfdqczsdjvss09ikk7xoannmzyhxwl1q3d8kcsnwmfenacqvz
    [3] => 201712151016343f6fnxgkjpjuzemgp4pbay4s5aagky5bsa5t4wns7ka1admgzp
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `2017\S{60}`. This matches `2017`, followed by exactly `60` non-whitespace characters (`64` minus the four in `2017`).

To get all of the results, you're looking for **[`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)**:

```
$matches = array();
$string = "201712140148264celho2kam2t3ajsf3zaiwvwl424nb16es5n8r81ajbgvvo175201712140153182vfdqczsdjvss09ikk7xoannmzyhxwl1q3d8kcsnwmfenacqvz201712151016343f6fnxgkjpjuzemgp4pbay4s5aagky5bsa5t4wns7ka1admgzp";
$search = preg_match_all("/2017\S{60}/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 201712140148264celho2kam2t3ajsf3zaiwvwl424nb16es5n8r81ajbgvvo175
    [1] => 201712140153182vfdqczsdjvss09ikk7xoannmzyhxwl1q3d8kcsnwmfenacqvz
    [2] => 201712151016343f6fnxgkjpjuzemgp4pbay4s5aagky5bsa5t4wns7ka1admgzp
)
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/BtEZW)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Works perfectly and to spec. Thanks for explaining the code - I can see how it works and will apply this technique to other projects too.